# Parse drawn lines in Text file to integers

Tags: java, c#, vb.net, algorithm

I get one task to solve it, and I solve it but it seems that my algorithm is a bit complicated so I would like to hear other methods for solving this problem.

Here is the task:

In a text file there are drawn lines |. _, -, /, and \ and they are drawn in a way that represents a digital number, for example lines | one below the other represents number 1.

Here is the file content:

```
---   ---    |  |   |   -----
  /   __|    |  |___|   |____
  \   |      |      |       |
---   ---    |      |   ____|

|  |   |   -----
|  |___|   |____
|      |       |
|      |   ____|
```

So, I need an algorithm that will read those lines and recognize numbers and return them as integers. It doesn't have to be in any language, written pseudo code is ok, but algorithm written in C#, Java or VB.net are also welcome.

Thank you!

P.S. Excuse me for my English.

Comment: You can just place it in your question. Paste it, select it, and click on the "Code" formatting button in the editor.

Comment: please also include your current approach.

Comment: What is the grid size of these digits?

Comment: Are the numbers always written the same? Do they have a specific width/height? If yes, then write the characters in a list for each number and compare your file with that list.

Comment: Create a function to read four consecutive, non-empty lines into a string[4] array. Create a function to test the array to be empty at a column position; this will help you parse the lines into another string[4] array that holds one digit. Then recognize the digit..

Comment: I wonder why 2 would be so different from 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you store the list of possible numbers as some sort of signature. This is a chain of characters that represent that number.

```
    Dim numbers As New List(Of String)

    numbers.Add("||||") ' 1
    numbers.Add("---__||  ---") ' 2
    numbers.Add("---  /  \---") ' 3
    numbers.Add("|   ||___|    |    |") ' 4
    numbers.Add("-----|____    |____|") ' 5
```

Read your file 4 lines at a time. Making sure to skip all empty lines. I hope all lines have the same width.

```
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)

    lines.add("---   ---    |  |   |   -----")
    lines.add("  /   __|    |  |___|   |____")
    lines.add("  \   |      |      |       |")
    lines.add("---   ---    |      |   ____|")
```

Loop all columns for each columns, loop all possible digit size. On each of those loop, find the possible signature. See if that signature is part of your initial list.

```
    For column As Integer = 0 To lines(0).Length - 1
        If Not IsColumnEmpty(lines, column) Then
            For digitSize As Integer = 1 To 5
                ' Don't overflow
                If column + digitSize > lines(0).Length Then
                    Exit For
                End If

                Dim signature As String

                signature = GetSignature(lines, column, digitSize)

                If numbers.Contains(signature) Then
                    Console.Write(numbers.IndexOf(signature) + 1)
                    column += digitSize ' Skip all columns that are part of this number
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

' We want to skip empty columns
Function IsColumnEmpty(ByVal lines As List(Of String), ByVal column As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim isEmpty As Boolean = True

    For Each line As String In lines
        If line(column) <> " " Then
            isEmpty = False
        End If
    Next

    Return isEmpty
End Function

' startingColumn and columnSize represent a square of data inside the 2d array. Convert that square into a 1d string
Function GetSignature(ByVal lines As List(Of String), ByVal startingColumn As Integer, ByVal columnSize As Integer)

    Dim signature As String = ""

    For Each line As String In lines
        signature &= line.Substring(startingColumn, columnSize)
    Next

    Return signature
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this problem was to consider each number like matrix (e.g.: number 1 in our sample is matrix with dimension 1x4) and that every line in digit number has its own coordinate. In that matrix I wanted to find and count all direction changes in the number (direction change means that two different lines are connected together e.g.: for number 2 we have 4 direction change) and to determinate exactly position in matrix ( left-top, right-top, right-middle, left-down,...)  So when I have the number of direction changes, what kind of direction change there are (e.g: |_ is left-down corner), and position where they are, I can recognize a number (e.g. number 2 has 4 direction change and they are: right-top corner on right-top position, right-down corner on middle-right position, left-top corner on middle-left position and left-down corner on left-down position, number 1 there is no direction changes and all lines are equal |, and so on). I chose this Algorithm because, it doesn't matter with how many lines are numbers drawn as long as they are properly connected and each numbers is properly separated.